# How to have a Seperate REST API that only handles authentication for multiple app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have developed multiple Django REST APIs, each with their own user authentication system, using tokens for authentication. I want to have all the APIs only use a single authentication database such that I can have a single front end where a user can log in, and then access multiple apps, each using their own API.

Is there a way whereby an API can make an API call to a central API with a user database for authentication? Or What would be industry/best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Jason Web Tokens for this, whereby as user is authenticated with a "central" API, and then given a Jason Web Token, all other apps that have the same key, can then use this JWT to check authentication, you can read more about it here:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework/#:~:text=JSON%20Web%20Token%20is%20an,storing%20sessions%20on%20the%20server](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework/#:%7E:text=JSON%20Web%20Token%20is%20an,storing%20sessions%20on%20the%20server).